# trash-cli on different BTRFS subvolume

Tags: delete, btrfs, trash

I have a @home BTRFS subvolume which mounts `/home/MYUSER`, and a @ subvolume which mounts /.

I keep my data on /mnt/dataint/data/SOMETHING.

I can't trash from `/mnt/dataint/data/SOMETHING`. The two subvolumes are really on the same physical drives, it's just the default filesystem structure that I got:

```
❯ trash -v MYFILE.backup 
trash: volume of file: /
trash: trying trash dir: /home/MYUSER/.local/share/Trash from volume: /home
trash: won't use trash dir ~/.local/share/Trash because its volume (/home) in a different volume than MYFILE.backup (/)
trash: found unusable .Trash dir (should be a dir): /.Trash
trash: trash directory is not secure: /.Trash/1000
trash: trying trash dir: /.Trash-1000 from volume: /
trash: failed to trash MYFILE.backup in /.Trash-1000, because: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.Trash-1000'
trash: cannot trash regular file 'MYFILE.backup'
```

I really want to use `/home/MYUSER/.local/share/Trash` as that would be compatible with my desktop environment.